# Getting a date for the current Sunday and previous Sundays

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 2.3.5 / Ruby 1.8.6

Looking for how to do this without the Rails 3 week classes.   I need to get the dates (2011-10-16, etc) for:
-The Sunday date of the current week
-The Sunday date of the previous 4 weeks

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I rely on the [chronic](https://github.com/mojombo/chronic/) library for such things, because I don't have to think too much to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I thought beginning_of_week was only in Rails 3 but this actually works fine in Rails 2:

```
sunday_this_week = (Time.now.beginning_of_week - 1.days).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
sunday_1_week_ago = (Time.now.beginning_of_week - 8.days).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
sunday_2_week_ago = (Time.now.beginning_of_week - 15.days).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
sunday_3_week_ago = (Time.now.beginning_of_week - 22.days).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
sunday_4_week_ago = (Time.now.beginning_of_week - 29.days).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```